# How to nest html when looping through array using Angular + ngFor / ng-template?

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-template

I'm trying to output html in the following format for an array

`weekDaysHeaderArr` whose length is 42 = 6 x 7.

In other words I want to nest every 7 column div elements in a row div (6 total) like so.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-auto"> <-- **repeated 7 times**
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-auto"> <-- **repeated 7 times**
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-auto"> <-- **repeated 7 times**
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-auto"> <-- **repeated 7 times**
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-auto"> <-- **repeated 7 times**
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-auto"> <-- **repeated 7 times**
    </div>
</div>
```

I can use `ngFor` to obviously produce the same html element (`div class="col-md-auto">`) 42 times but how do I nest every 7 elements inside a `<div class="row">` ?

I've not used `ng-template` and `ng-container` before and I can't get my head around the documentation, can these be used to do this? As far as I can tell these are designed for switching between html elements rather than nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a matrix from your array

```js
private weekDaysHeaderArr = [ /*Your elements here*/ ]
private groupSize: number = 7;
get matrix(){ 
  return this.weekDaysHeaderArr.map((item, index, arr)=>{
    return index % this.groupSize === 0 ? arr.slice(index, index + this.groupSize) : null; 
  })
  .filter((item) => { return item; });
}
```

Then use it inside your template like this

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let week of matrix">
    <div class="col-md-auto" *ngFor="let day of week">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: needs to be `this.groupSize` but yeah, works out the box

Answer (score 1):

Nesting for-loops in angular template is pretty straightforward. Given you have two separate arrays, you can do the following:

```
const sixThings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

const weekdays = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed']

<div class="row" *ngFor="let thing of sixThings"> <-- **repeated 6 times**
    <div class="col-md-auto" *ngFor="let weekday of weekdays"> <-- **repeated 7 times**
    </div>
</div>
```

I'll update the answer later for the case where you have a nested array already, or can compose one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this....

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let week of [0,1,2,3,4,5]">
    <div class="col-md-auto" *ngFor="let day of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">
    </div>
</div>
```

then, to get the index from weekDaysHeaderArr you can do....

```
 weekDaysHeaderArr[week * 7 + day];
```

Comment: I get `Binding expression cannot contain chained expression at the end of the expression` when trying to use `weekDaysHeaderArr[week * 7 + day];`

Comment: @AndrewAllen Can you show the html from the outer loop all the way in?

Comment: @AndrewAllen if you want to use let day of week you can define week as Array(6).fill([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]), and use the index of week inside weekDaysHeaderArr