# Angular 7 iterate table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops, angular-template

I want to iterate table with one property but to have 4 td in one row, and to continue like that till the end...

I want like this:

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <mat-checkbox>1</mat-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-checkbox>2</mat-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-checkbox>3</mat-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-checkbox>4</mat-checkbox>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <mat-checkbox>5</mat-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-checkbox>6</mat-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-checkbox>7</mat-checkbox>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I tried like this, but it's al in one column :

```js
lista = [
    { value: "1" },
    { value: "2" },
    { value: "3" },
    { value: "4" },
    { value: "5" },
    { value: "6" },
    { value: "7" },
```

```html
<table *ngFor="let list of lista">
   <tr>
     <td>
       <mat-checkbox>{{ list.value }}</mat-checkbox>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: There is no issue... this code render every value one bellow other, but I want in one row to be 4 values and then to break row and start another.

Comment: adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55809153/4711754) answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group your array firstly in groups of `4` (chunk size), then iterate over it simply in your template.

In your component:

```
const lista = [
    { value: "1" },
    { value: "2" },
    { value: "3" },
    { value: "4" },
    { value: "5" },
    { value: "6" },
    { value: "7" }
];

const chunkSize = 4;

// Group in chunks of 4 and take only truthy values
const groups = lista
.map((x, index) => { 
     return index % chunkSize === 0 ? lista.slice(index, index + chunkSize): null; 
})
.filter(x => x);
```

In your template:

```
<table >
   <tr *ngFor="let item of groups">
     <td *ngFor = "let innerItem of item">
       <mat-checkbox>{{ innerItem.value }}</mat-checkbox>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's exactly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2d array for your table like below:

```
  lista = [
[
  {value: '1'},
  {value: '2'},
  {value: '3'},
  {value: '4'}
],

[
  {value: '5'},
  {value: '6'},
  {value: '7'},
  {value: '8'}
]
 ];
```

and for HTML

```
<table >
  <tr *ngFor="let row of lista">
    <td *ngFor="let col of row">
      <mat-checkbox>{{ col.value }}</mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired table structure with four  elements in each row, you can modify the iteration logic in your Angular template. Here's an updated version of the code:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let list of lista; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="i % 4 === 0">
      </tr><tr>
    </ng-container>
    <td>
      <mat-checkbox>{{ list.value }}</mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this updated code, the  element is closed and reopened using  every four iterations. This ensures that a new row is started after every four  elements.

The expression i % 4 === 0 checks if the current index (i) is divisible by 4, indicating the start of a new row. If it is, the  tags are rendered to close the current row and open a new one.

With this approach, the  elements will be distributed into rows with four checkboxes in each row until the end of the list is reached.